# qt creator error on "import QtMultimedia"

Tags: qt, ubuntu, import, qml, qtmultimedia

Recently, I have been studying on Qt5 Audio and followed this youtube lecture.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dh6ax1xVJD0

During the course I had to put the line into one of 'qml' file

```
import QtMultimedia 5.0
```

The name "QtMultimedia 5.0" came up automatically so did the help menu.
However, the line has red underline that says "QML module not found Import paths:..."

How may I fix this problem?
OS: Ubuntu
Project build steps: Applications => "Qt Quick UI" => "Qt Quick 2.0"

Thank you for reading my story.
JB

Comment: It depends on the environment variable QML2_IMPORT_PATH as shown [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/25104/qml-module-not-found-and-designer-shows-no-gui).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
QT += multimedia
```

to your .pro file

Answer (score 0):

try this command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path-to-your-qt-installation/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/gcc_64/lib` it helped me with similar issue with PyQt and QML